# User access using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes

I want to set multiple accounts to only have access only to owned namespace, we try with authorization mode ABAC but we get when use kubectl "error: couldn't read version from server: the server does not allow access to the requested ressource" and it seems to be a bug. Is theire other way to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Before attempting to access your resources, kubectl first makes requests to the server's `/version` and `/api` endpoints to confirm compatibility and negotiate API version. In ABAC, the `/version` and `/api` endpoints are considered "nonResourcePaths", but those also require authorization. You can add a rule to your ABAC file allowing all users readonly access to nonResourcePaths as follows:

```
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"*", "nonResourcePath": "*", "readonly": true}}
```

From there, you can make it more restrictive if you need to.

Comment: The example ABAC file at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/auth/authorizer/abac/example_policy_file.jsonl might be helpful to look at.

Comment: When I do like this user can get all namespaces, services, ... . my config : {"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"testuser","namespace": "testuser","resource": "pods","apiGroup": "*", "readonly": true}}